# IUPAC Nomenclature for cyclic compounds without principal functional group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I am struggling naming cyclic compounds with multiple substituents and no principle functional group . If anyone can please elaborate the rules, it would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: Nomenclature gets variegated there. And hybrid nomenclature is tolerated (at least it was..).

Comment: I have provided example, here I don't understand where to start numbering from.

Comment: I would call this 2-chloro-4-nitrotoluene.

Comment: @AravindSuresh And you would be correct if the question were about *any* name. PIN though is **2‐chloro‐1‐methyl‐4‐nitrobenzene**.